# Conflict between eval and print in Perl

Tags: regex, perl, printing, eval

I'm creating a subroutine in my Perl script and can evaluate it nicely and it works. I would also like to print the content of the subroutine for debugging purposes. However, the subroutine, which is constructed in `code`, is really huge and is hard to read and understand it by simply printing it. I would like to find a way to be able to print it in a semi-indented way.

Here is piece of `code` generation:

```
$code .= "if (\$ct=~/^\\s*\$/x  || \$Im < \$Ix) {push(\@min, $b); push(\@max, $b);} if (\$Im > \$Ix) {push(\@min, $a); push(\@max, $a);}"
```

And I would like to print it something like this:

```
if (\$ct=~/^\\s*\$/x  || \$Im < \$Ix)
    {push(\@min, $b); push(\@max, $b);}
if (\$Im > \$Ix)
    {push(\@min, $a); push(\@max, $a);}
```

I know that the straight way to do this is to write another script to parse it and put some `\n` and `\t` into the appropriate places in `code` and then print it. Is there a smarter way to that?

Like putting `\n` somewhere in `code` without subverting `eval`ing it (i.e., something visible to `print` but invisible to `eval`).

**NOTE:** I have a lot of regexes in my subroutine and I want to avoid running them every time. That's why I need to have the code stored in a string and then `eval` it to increase my script performance.

Comment: Why do you need `eval` in the first place?

Comment: This subroutine will be called somewhere in my script. I'll run it by `eval`.

Comment: Why not just...call the subroutine?

Comment: OK, I need the code itself to be stored.

Comment: Again, why? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: There is just about no good reason to build up a bunch of code in a string and then eval it... Just run the code rather than building the string. This seems like an X-Y problem to me.

Comment: want nice-printed perl code what is stored as an string - use Perl::Tidy.

Comment: @AKHolland [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24565533/2884483) shows a real-world case where a generated subroutine was necessary to avoid a major performance hit. Also, seconding what jm666 said; the easiest thing to do would be to print it out and pipe it to perltidy. Trying to prettify generated Perl code just makes the code doing the generation uglier.

Comment: @Slade The key words in AKHolland's statement are *just about* no good reason; that's not the same as never. The OP of this question, however, has provided no evidence that `eval` is necessary for what they're trying to do.

Comment: It was so hard to explain it. @Slade Thanks for providing a great example! I actually want to do this for a very similar reason.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot Why are you insisting on saying "no necessity of using `eval`". Instead, if you know, contribute in a way that the question is asked!

Comment: @user3761870 Because it's dangerous, hard to maintain, and usually unnecessary. If somebody asks how to aim a gun at their foot and pull the trigger, I will advise them not to, unless they tell me that a flesh-eating zombie is nibbling on their toes like they're cocktail weenies. What's your flesh-eating zombie?

Comment: Looking at your edit: you can precompile regexes with [`qr`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Regexp-Quote-Like-Operators) to improve performance.

Comment: What do you mean by *"I have a lot of regex in my subroutine and I want to avoid running them every time. That's why I need to have the code stored in string and then eval it to increase my script performance."* Please show an example of code that you think will run faster if you use `eval` at run time.

Comment: @remmargorp: My guess is that you are generating Perl code at run time. There are several reasons to choose that approach, but I wish you had explained that that is what you are doing. Even so your approach is clumsy; for instance there is no need to use double quotes for your code when single quotes avoid the need to escape every `$` and `@`. I think it is best if you submit what you have to [Stack Exchange's Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25319236/perl-debugging-subroutines-stored-in-strings-and-called-by-eval) I asked another question which hopefully explains the necessity of storing `subs` in strings and `eval`ing them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ignoring the reasons why you may have code in a string...

[`Perl::Tidy`](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Perl-Tidy/lib/Perl/Tidy.pod) is the tool that you need to reformat your code.

Normally, one uses this tool via the command line on source files.  However, I've hacked together a little script that will output your code string to a temporary file so that it can be reformatted.  Note, this currently assumes that your code is well-formed and that there aren't any obvious syntax errors in it as formatting broken code is outside the purview of this tool.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

my $code = <<'END_CODE';
# It hurts to write ugly code, but I'll see what I can do
sub { my @vars = @_;
 my $count = scalar(@vars); print "Hello World.  Vars = $count"; return; }
END_CODE

print pretty_code($code);

sub pretty_code {
    my $code = shift;

    require File::Temp;
    require Perl::Tidy;

    my ($fh, $filename) = File::Temp::tempfile();
    print $fh $code;
    close $fh;

    Perl::Tidy::perltidy(
        source => $filename,
    );

    my $output = do {
        open my $fh, '<', "$filename.tdy";
        local $/;
        <$fh>
    };

    unlink $_ for ($filename, "$filename.tdy");

    return $output;
}
```

Outputs:

```
# It hurts to write ugly code, but I'll see what I can do
sub {
    my @vars  = @_;
    my $count = scalar(@vars);
    print "Hello World.  Vars = $count";
    return;
  }
```

---

**Update**

There is no need to use a temporary file, particularly as `Perl::Tidy` accumulates the tidied code in memory before dumping it to disk. If you prefer, this program does the same thing without writing the result to disk.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Perl::Tidy 'perltidy';

my $code = <<'END_CODE';
# It hurts to write ugly code, but I'll see what I can do
sub { my @vars = @_; my $count = scalar(@vars); print "Hello World.  Vars = $count"; return; }
END_CODE

print pretty_code($code);

sub pretty_code {
   my ($code) = @_;
   my $pretty;

   perltidy(
      source      => \$code,
      destination => \$pretty,
   );

   $pretty;
}
```

**output**

```
# It hurts to write ugly code, but I'll see what I can do
sub {
  my @vars  = @_;
  my $count = scalar(@vars);
  print "Hello World.  Vars = $count";
  return;
    }
```

I'm not clear at present why the closing brace is indented further, but I am certain that the result is better than the original.

Comment: Thanks @Miller. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25319236/perl-debugging-subroutines-stored-in-strings-and-called-by-eval) I asked another question which hopefully explains the necessity of storing `subs` in strings and `eval`ing them.

Comment: @Borodin I spent literally 20 minutes trying to get string references to work, but I kept on getting errors.  It works now though, so thanks for confirming that either I'm crazy or my dev environment was for a little bit.

Comment: @remmargorp: (Please note that I am not the author of the answer above, although the *Update* is mine.) I have read the question that you linked and can still see no reason to choose your design. The code that you show in the earlier question doesn't compile so it is really hard to guess what you are doing.

Comment: @Miller: It happens! I hope you don't mind the edit.