# Perl: debugging subroutines stored in strings and called by eval

Tags: regex, perl, debugging, eval

I do a lot of `regex` on file `A`. Based on my parsing, I create many subroutines and store them in a hash , `$code` --in subroutine `f`.

```
sub f
{
    #REGEX on file A
    $code = { "a0" => "sub { my $x = shift; .... return 0*x;}",
              "a1" => "sub { my $x = shift; .... return 1*x;}",
              ....
              "a9" => "sub { my $x = shift; .... return 9*x;}",
            }
}
```

The hash values of `code` are the generated subroutines and the keys are some other strings.

Then, using subroutine `g`, I do lots of `regex` on file `B` and get some keys and then call the corresponding subroutine from `code` by `eval`ing `$code{$key}($x)`.

```
sub g
{
    #REGEX on file B to get the keys and x`s
    foreach $keys{
        print $code{keys}($x) 
   }
}
```

I do this ugly job (instead of calling `f`) to avoid multiple `regex`ing over `A`. However, this makes debugging `sub f` a tedious job --since I don't have the actual keys coming from `B` in `A`. Unless, I put some, `print`ing statement in `$code` itself. I avoid doing this, since I'd rather to keep the functionality of `$code` as it is (with no LOG statement).

Any remedy for my problem?

Answer (score 2):

You can assign the name to `local *__ANON__` (see [Named anonymous subs at PerlMonks](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=304883)), or you can use [Sub::Name](http://p3rl.org/Sub::Name) (BTW, one of the suggestions in the linked thread).